# when using picker the dropdown is not working for me

Tags: react-native, expo, picker

This is a simplification of the code but I have several pickers and they don't work correctly for me, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
import { Picker } from '@react-native-picker/picker';

export default function ProfileScreen() {

  const [ province, setProvince ] = useState("madrid")

     return (
       <>
           <View style={styles.picker_and_inputs}>
               <Picker
                  selectedValue={province}
                  onValueChange={(value, itemIndex) => setProvince({value})}
                  mode="dropdown"
               >
                  <Picker.Item label="Madrid" value="madrid" />
                  <Picker.Item label="Barcelona" value="barcelona" />
                  <Picker.Item label="Cataluña" value="cataluña" />
               </Picker>
          </View>
       </>
     );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consoled logged what onValueChange was returning

```js
onValueChange={(value, itemIndex) => console.log(value)}
```

and got a string

`madrid`

Thus all you need to do is change from this

```js
onValueChange={(value, itemIndex) => setProvince({value})}
```

to this.

```js
onValueChange={(value, itemIndex) => setProvince(value)}
```

Everything works fine now just remove those brackets.Full Example here (https://snack.expo.dev/@heytony01/insane-pretzel)

Comment: Yes, I had it like that, but it won't let me press the picker, let's say, and I'm testing it with the same code you gave me above. I am using an Android pixel 4 xl emulator

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@mateomazzucco11/carefree-toffee

Comment: I put the whole code in this code, it is not working on me! But that would be the code in reality and it is not doing the dropdown

Comment: I fix the problem, is a container element. Thanks